# Use Content Type from Subsite on Parent Site

Tags: 2013, content-type, visual-studio-2013

I have two content types on a subsite with their fields, and i need to use his content type on a parent site, on library Document, i have already add the reference for those two content types in library document (Parent Site) but when i try, i see those two content type but no fields !

Library document is on Project and content types on other project, bu the same solution.

I have also activated the feature on parent site but nothing.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to do it the other way. Content types created on a subsite is not inherited by the parent site.

Create the content types on the parent site and they will be available on all the sub sites below it.

Or create a content type hub and manage all your content types from there and publish them to all your sites. [Publish a content type from a content publishing hub](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Publish-a-content-type-from-a-content-publishing-hub-58081155-118d-4e7a-9cc5-d43b5dbb7d02)